# Will redirecting a URL that has been 410 for months pass its link juice and help SEO?

Tags: 301-redirect, links, 410-gone

Is it too late to pass the link juice to the new URL from the old ones when the old URL was set as 410 content for the past 5 months? Does Googlebot delete the old ranking of previous URLs after this long?

Comment: Google remove URLs from the index right away when Googlebot discovers that they have 410 Gone status.  The question isn't whether the old URL ranks (it clearly doesn't), the question is whether Google would ignore links to that old URL that were created before it went away for months.